# Why does Scala compiler fail with "object SparkConf in package spark cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I cannot access the `SparkConf` in the package. But I have already import the `import org.apache.spark.SparkConf`. My code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

object SparkStreaming {
    def main(arg: Array[String]) = {

        val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
        val ssc = new StreamingContext( conf, Seconds(1) )

        val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
        val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
        val pairs_new = words.map( w => (w, 1) )
        val wordsCount = pairs_new.reduceByKey(_ + _)
        wordsCount.print() 

        ssc.start() // Start the computation
        ssc.awaitTermination() // Wait for the computation to the terminate

    }
}
```

The `sbt` dependencies are:

```
name := "Spark Streaming"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.5.2",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.5.2"
)
```

But the error shows that `SparkConf` cannot be accessed.

```
[error] /home/cliu/Documents/github/Spark-Streaming/src/main/scala/Spark-Streaming.scala:31: object SparkConf in package spark cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark
[error]         val conf = new SparkConf.setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
[error]                        ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It compiles if you add parenthesis after SparkConf:

`val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")`

The point is that SparkConf is a class and not a function, so you could use class name also for scope purposes. So when you add parenthesis after the class name, you are making sure you are calling the class constructor and not the scoping functionality. Here is an example from Scala shell illustrating the difference:

```
scala> class C1 { var age = 0; def setAge(a:Int) = {age = a}}
defined class C1

scala> new C1
res18: C1 = $iwC$$iwC$C1@2d33c200

scala> new C1()
res19: C1 = $iwC$$iwC$C1@30822879

scala> new C1.setAge(30)  // this doesn't work

<console>:23: error: not found: value C1
          new C1.setAge(30)
              ^

scala> new C1().setAge(30) // this works

scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you cannot omit parentheses so it should be:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
```