# Getting Spark Logging class not found when using Spark SQL

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to do a simple Spark SQL programming in Java. In the program, I am getting data from a Cassandra table, converting the `RDD` into a `Dataset` and displaying the data. When I run the `spark-submit` command, I am getting the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging`.

My program is:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DataFrameTest")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "abc")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "def")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "ghi");
SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaRDD<EventLog> logsRDD = javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable("test", "log",
        mapRowTo(Log.class));
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark SQL").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> logsDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(logsRDD, Log.class);
logsDF.show();
```

My POM dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

My `spark-submit` command is: `/home/ubuntu/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --class "com.jtv.spark.dataframes.App" --master local[4] spark.dataframes-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

How do I solve this error? Downgrading to `1.5.2` does not work as `1.5.2` does not have `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` and `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`.

Comment: @T.Gawęda The solution there does not work for me because downgrading to 1.5.2 as 1.5.2 does not have `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` and `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`.

Comment: Please check connector version 2.0 - see https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: @T.Gawęda Connector 2.0 is still in beta. I used it and I get this error: `NullPointerException
 at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:465)NullPointerException
 at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:465)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.getSchema(SparkSession.scala:673)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:340)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:359)
 at com.jtv.spark.dataframes.App.main(App.java:25)`

Comment: But Connector 1.6 does not support Spark 2.x. This error means you've got wrong guava version. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and find where you've got conflicts

Comment: @T.Gawęda I get this error when I use Connector 2.0.0-M3 not 1.6. I had used Connector 1.6 with Spark 2.0 in other programs. The problem starts when I use Spark SQL packages.

Comment: In pom.xml you have `<version>1.6.3</version>` ;) Spark uses Guava and maybe some other lib on the classpath also and  there is a version conflict

Comment: @T.Gawęda I changed it at your suggestion. I posted the result in the comment which showed a guava version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a problem into your IDE. As some of this packages are created and Scala the Java project, sometimes the IDE is unable to understand what is going on. I am using the Intellij and it keeps displaying this message to me. But, when I try to run the "mvn test" or "mvn package" everything is fine. Please check if this is really some package error or just the IDE that is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Logging is available for Spark version `1.5.2` and lower but not higher version. So your dependency in `pom.xml` should be like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
  </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. 1.5.2 does not have `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` and `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`.

Comment: Then for them you can use updated version and for other the older version. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Khateeb Hi did you tried the solution what error its showing now.

Comment: Getting error: `[24,57] cannot access org.apache.spark.internal.Logging`

Comment: @Khateeb I think their is some problem in spark configuration. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108613/why-does-scala-compiler-fail-with-object-sparkconf-in-package-spark-cannot-be-a

Comment: I have been running other programs using the same Spark config with no problem. This problem started when I started to use Spark SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129911/discussion-between-sachinsarawgi-and-khateeb).

Answer (score 0):

The below dependency worked fine for my case.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party here, but I added

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To solve this issue.  Seems to work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct spark version in the pom.xml.

previously, in local,  I have a different version of Spark and that is why I was getting the error in IntelliJ IDE. "Can not have access Spark.logging class"

In my case, Changed it from 2.4.2 -> 2.4.3, and it solved.

Spark version & Scala version info, we can get from spark-shell command.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```