# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a SparkSession (to run NaiveBayes model) in spark but getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.bnym.spark.SparkML.App.main(App.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

My java code is very simple:

```
package com.bnym.spark.SparkML;

import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayesModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

/**
 * Naive Bayes Example
 *
 */
public class App 
{
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
  //System.out.println( "Hello World!" );       
  SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("NB")
    .getOrCreate();

  // Load training data
  //Dataset<Row> dataFrame = spark.read().format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt");
 }
}
```

And my pom.xml file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bnym.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>SparkML</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SparkML</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.0</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>  

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.0</version>    
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Would really appreciate help in figuring out why the error.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995462/getting-spark-logging-class-not-found-when-using-spark-sql

Comment: Actually 1.5.2 version does not help. Cannot import: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession; org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;